# Parallel execute oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, parallel-processing, package

Basically I have a package in oracle 11g processing a file and validating and inserting information in multiple tables, 
    to achiev this I create a stored procedure that reads the file and spread the information, then I call multiple stored procedures to
    validate and insert the data in each table (one procedure per table), for errors each SP insert a record in a common error table, at the end, 
    I call one last stored procedure that identifies if there is errors in the common error table and generate a file with those errors.

Now... I'm trying to improve the code in order to minimize times of execution, then I realice that each SP that validates and insert info
    into table does not depend from other SP information, so I'm asking if there is a way to call all this SP in parallel.

TODAY

```
STORED PROCEDURE charge_file
STORED PROCEDURE insert_table1
STORED PROCEDURE insert_table2
STORED PROCEDURE insert_table3 ...
STORED PROCEDURE return_file
```

What I am trying to do

```
STORED PROCEDURE charge_file
STORED PROCEDURE insert_table1 - STORED PROCEDURE insert_table2 - STORED PROCEDURE insert_table3 ...
STORED PROCEDURE return_file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As example using parallel_execute:

```
create table proc_map (proc_id number, proc_name varchar2(64), is_active varchar2(1));

insert into proc_map (proc_id, proc_name, is_active) values (1, 'insert_table1', 'Y');
insert into proc_map (proc_id, proc_name, is_active) values (2, 'insert_table2', 'Y');
insert into proc_map (proc_id, proc_name, is_active) values (3, 'insert_table3', 'Y');


create or replace procedure p_run_proc (ip_start in number, ip_end in number)  is
  v_proc_name proc_map.proc_name%type;
begin
  begin
    select t.proc_name into v_proc_name 
    from proc_map t
    where t.proc_id = ip_start;
  exception
    when no_data_found then null;
    when too_many_rows then null;
  end;

  if v_proc_name is not null
    then
      execute immediate 'begin ' || v_proc_name || '; end;';
  end if;
end;

declare
  v_task_name varchar2(4000) := dbms_parallel_execute.generate_task_name;
  v_sql varchar2(4000);
  v_run varchar2(4000);
  v_thread_count number;
  v_task_status number;
begin
  dbms_parallel_execute.create_task (task_name => v_task_name);

  v_sql := 'select t.proc_id as num_col 
                  ,t.proc_id as num_col
            from proc_map t 
            where t.is_active = ''Y'' 
            order by t.proc_id';

  dbms_parallel_execute.create_chunks_by_SQL (task_name => v_task_name, sql_stmt => v_sql, by_rowid => false);

  v_run := 'begin p_run_proc (ip_start => :start_id, ip_end => :end_id); end;';

  select count(*) into v_thread_count 
  from proc_map t
  where t.is_active = 'Y';

  dbms_parallel_execute.run_task (task_name => v_task_name
                                 ,sql_stmt => v_run
                                 ,language_flag => dbms_sql.native
                                 ,parallel_level => v_thread_count);

  v_task_status := dbms_parallel_execute.task_status (task_name => v_task_name);

  if v_task_status = dbms_parallel_execute.FINISHED
    then
      dbms_parallel_execute.drop_task (task_name => v_task_name);
    else
      raise_application_error (-20001, 'ORA in task ' || v_task_name);
  end if;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in fork/background submit in PL/SQL, other than [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm) or the older [DBMS_JOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_job.htm). (DBMS_SCHEDULER is more fully featured and has far better tracking for failures.) I wrote a job control object a few years ago as a project but to be honest I've never used it. [www.williamrobertson.net/documents/job-control-object.html](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/job-control-object.html)

Answer (score -2):

You can use run_job or submit.

Refer below link for example :-
http://www.dba-oracle.com/r_execute_pl_sql_in_parallel.htm